# how to edit unity exported gradle project in android studio (mainly unity's .cs files / scripts)

Tags: c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

I have exported a game made in Unity and exported it to Android studio (using Unity build panel, using Gradle build with export option ticked) in Unity.

Then I went to Android studio and imported the project. Got lots of problems in the process (build.gradle errors and many more), spending lots of hours until all errors are fixed by now (meaning I can test the app on my mobile).

Now I want some of the .cs files edited. **I need to update and change some of the scripts**. *But I don't want to go back to Unity, edit them, and recreate another build, and then import the project to Android studio, and then work another 2 days to fix the problems*.

Now I would like to edit .cs files somehow without redoing the above process, but I can't find any of the files I had in the imported project folder.

Can anyone please help me? 
Note: I am a very inexperienced coder, so I appreciate keeping this mind while responding, thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unfortunately...

You will have to go back to Unity, edit them, and recreate another build, and then import the project to Android studio. Then probably work another 2 days to fix the problems.

After compiling your scripts are not in any sort of readable format: it's been compiled down to a dll or other similar binary. You can confirm this by searching your (Android Studio) project for a string that you know appears in one of your scripts.  You won't be able to find it.

Comment: oh no! that's such a big bummer! the worst of all is that my unity won't build the project itself due to lots of conflicting dex and other build issues, that's why I build it using gradle export setting for android so I could better manage to fix the issues. 
Ok, thanks for prompt guiding, I guess I'll have to suffer the pain and go that route as you've suggested, thanks!