# How can i add extra line of code on unity's export project to android studio?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I know this is similar to the question asked before

> ### [how to edit unity exported gradle project in android studio (mainly unity's .cs files / scripts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118379/how-to-edit-unity-exported-gradle-project-in-android-studio-mainly-unitys-cs)

But the thing is that i don't want to edit the project , i only want is to add some activity and layout that i design. ***I know it is possible to add some line of code but could not find proper resource.*** so how to add some line of code without affecting existing code ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [platform dependant compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).

This allows for code to only run on specific platforms (i.e Android)

It'd like this:

```
private void Foo()
{
   //Some logic that run on all devices
#if UNITY_ANDROID
   //This logic is only run when it is to be run on an android device, so you could add the code to add the layout here
#endif
   //Rest of the logic that runs on all devices
}
```

After you've build your project it becomes impossible to edit the original code and make it work as if it was edited pre-compilation

Comment: Where shall i add this Foo() method ? i have one class UnityPlayerActivity . Shall i include in here ?